# Getting Cycle names from Releases in HP ALM?

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center, alm

I have successfully retrived all the fields from Testsets and Defects sections by creating object in the following way. (By using C#)

```
TDConnection qcc = qccTDConnection;
BugFactory bfact = (BugFactory)qcc.BugFactory;
List bugs = (List)bfact.NewList(bf.Filter.Text);

foreach (TDAPIOLELib.Bug bg in bugs)
{
   status = Convert.ToString(bg["BG_STATUS"]);
   assignTo = bg.AssignedTo.ToString();
   priority = Convert.ToString(bg["BG_PRIORITY"]); // PRIORITY VERY HIGH
 }
```

This is fine ,But now i want to get the fields from Releses (cycles, folder... ). Here i tried like below but it couldnt work.

```
ReleaseFolderfactory rel = (Release)qcc.ReleaseFolderFactory;
List listRel = (List)rel.NewList(rel.Filter.Text);
foreach(TDAPIOLELib.Release rl in listRel)
{
  string PlanStartDate = Convert.ToString(rl["RCYC_START_DATE"]);
  string PlanEndDate = Convert.ToString(rl["RCYC_START_DATE"]);

}
```

Any one help me to solve this.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... Here is the solution.

ReleaseFactory rel = qcc.ReleaseFactory;
            List listRel = (List)rel.NewList(rel.Filter.Text);

```
        foreach (TDAPIOLELib.Release rl in listRel)
        {

            string RelStartDate = Convert.ToString(rl.StartDate);
            string RelEndDate = Convert.ToString(rl.EndDate);
            CycleFactory CyF = rl.CycleFactory;

            foreach (TDAPIOLELib.Cycle Cyc in CyF.NewList(""))
             {
                    string CycleStartDate = Convert.ToString(Cyc.StartDate);
                    string CycleEndDate = Convert.ToString(Cyc.EndDate);

             }



        }
```